# RecyclerView hacer clic y reemplazar imagen desde otra actividad

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview, programación-móvil

Tengo unas dudas de como solucionar la duda de como hacer clic en un RecyclerView y que cambie de imagen desde otra actividad, como por ejemplo el MainActivity.

En la imagen podrás ver que estoy intentando hacer. Tengo un total de 6 imágenes, 3 imágenes Pequeñas y otras 3 imágenes Grandes.

En el pie del MainActivity tengo el ReciclerView que carga las 3 imágenes pequeñas, quiero que cuando pinchen por ejemplo a la imagen_Pequeña_2/item_Pequeña_2, que remplazaca la imagen que esta en el centro por la imagen_Grande_2/item_Grande_2.

No se si me estoy explicando bien, os dejo una captura y el código para ver si podéis echarme una mano. Gracias de antemano.
*P.D.* Utilizo la librería glide para cargar las imágenes.

**Mi Adaptador del RecyclerView**

```
public class AdaptadorX extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorX.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Items> itemsLi;
    private Context context;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ImageView idSrcImagen;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            idSrcImagen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idImagen);
        }
    }

    public AdaptadorX(ArrayList<Items> itemsListado, Context context_L){
        itemsLi = itemsListado;
        context = context_L;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder content = new ViewHolder(view);
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Items contarItems =  itemsLi.get(position);
        Glide.with(context).load(contarItems.getxNombre_imagen()).into(holder.idSrcImagen);
        holder.idSrcImagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("Mensaje_AdaptadorX.java", "Mi Posicion FOTO es: "+String.valueOf(position));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("Mensaje_Size_Tamaño", String.valueOf(itemsLi.size()));
        return itemsLi.size();
    }

}
```

**Clase Items**

```
public class Items {
    private String xNombre_imagen;

    public Items (String nombre_imagen_M){
        xNombre_imagen = nombre_imagen_M;
    }

    public String getxNombre_imagen() {
        return xNombre_imagen;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ImageView idImgHead;
    private ArrayList<Items> items;
    private RecyclerView idRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        idRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.idRecyclerView);
        idImgHead = findViewById(R.id.idImgHead);
        Glide.with(this).load("https://www.midominio.com/Imagen_GRANDE_head_01.jpg").into(idImgHead); //IMAGEN GRANDE
        listadoXhead();
    }

    private void listadoXhead() {
        ArrayList<Items> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new Items("https://www.midominio.com/Imagen_Pequeña_head_01.jpg")); //IMAGEN Pequeña
        items.add(new Items("https://www.midominio.com/Imagen_Pequeña_head_02.jpg")); //IMAGEN Pequeña
        items.add(new Items("https://www.midominio.com/Imagen_Pequeña_head_03.jpg")); //IMAGEN Pequeña
        idRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).setOrientation(RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL);
        adapter = new AdaptadorX(items, MainActivity.this);
        idRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        idRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/idImgHead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/idRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/idImagen"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:onClick="accionBoton"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer lo que pides, tienes que declarar una interfaz **onItemClickListener** dentro de tu clase Adapter, de forma que pases al método **onItemClick** como parámetro la imagen y su posición.

**Adaptador del RecyclerView**

```
public interface onItemClickListener{  
    //Método que gestiona el click encima de un elemento  
    void onItemClick(int position);  
}
```

Ahora, en la clase donde quieres cambiar las imágenes (dónde instancias el adapter) deberías definir el comportamiento del método __onItemClick que has declarado en la interfaz.

**MainActivity**

```
adapter= new AdaptadorX(items, MainActivity.this, new AdaptadorX.onItemClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position){
        //Aquí defines el comportamiento cuando haces click (defines el cambio de imagen)
        idImgHead.setBackground = items.get(position);
    }
});
```

Y con ese código debería funcionarte sin problemas.
Espero que te sirva, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas maneras, pero esta es la que uso y creo que es de las más sencillas:

**Adaptador del RecyclerView**

```
...
private View.OnClickListener mOnShareClickListener;

void setOnShareClickListener(View.OnClickListener itemClickListener) {
    mOnShareClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    idSrcImagen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idImagen);

    // setTag() permite almacenar un objeto cualquiera para recuperarlo más tarde
    // así que también podrias guardar la posición en lugar del objeto (this)
    idSrcImagen.setTag(this);
    idSrcImagen.setOnClickListener(mOnImageClickListener);
}
...
```

**MainActivity**

```
...
private void listadoXhead() {
    adapter.setOnShareClickListener(new View.OnClickListener( ) {
        // En viewHolder ahora tienes el objeto view entero, en el que se a hecho click
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = (RecyclerView.ViewHolder) v.getTag( );
        // Cogemos la posición
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

        // Suponiendo que la lista tiene las imágenes pequeñas y grandes concatenadas de
        // esta forma: [pequeña1, grande1, pequeña2, grande2, pequeña3, grande3]
        // por ejemplo podrias sumarle 1 a la posición para obtener la grande a partir
        // de la pequeña
        position = position + 1
        Items contarItems =  itemsLi.get(position);
        Glide.with(context).load(contarItems.getxNombre_imagen()).into(idImgHead);
}
...
```

Hasta aquí sería todo. Pero parece que tu estructura dónde guardas las imágenes no es clara. En el código te he sugerido una forma (concatenarlas todas), pero una forma más sencilla en mi opinión seria guardar en la clase `Items` el nombre de la imagen grande y el de la pequeña:

```
public class Items {
    private String xNombre_imagen_grande;
    private String xNombre_imagen_pequena;

    public Items (String nombre_imagen_grande, String nombre_imagen_pequena){
        xNombre_imagen_grande = nombre_imagen_grande;
        xNombre_imagen_pequena = nombre_imagen_pequena;
    }

    public String getxNombre_imagen_pequena() {
        return xNombre_imagen_pequena;
    }

    public String getxNombre_imagen_grande() {
        return xNombre_imagen_grande;
    }
...
}
```

Así con la posición en el `setOnShareClickListener` sólo harías:

```
Items contarItems =  itemsLi.get(position);
Glide.with(context).load(contarItems.getxNombre_imagen_grande()).into(idImgHead);
```